# Using the caret package is it possible to obtain confusion matrices for specific threshold values?

Tags: r, classification, roc, caret, confusion-matrix

I've obtained a logistic regression model (via `train`) for a binary response, and I've obtained the logistic confusion matrix via `confusionMatrix` in `caret`. It gives me the logistic model confusion matrix, though I'm not sure what threshold is being used to obtain it. How do I obtain the confusion matrix for specific threshold values using `confusionMatrix` in `caret`?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but often questions like this are answered in the help file. If that fails, you can look at the source code itself. You can print the source to the console by typing `confusionmatrix`, without parentheses.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you have done exactly. Did you call the `glm` function from the `stats` package and pass its result to `confusionMatrix`? I didn't know one could do that, and reading the manual it isn't clear one can at all. Or did you `predict` something? A short example would help.

Comment: @Calimo I've used the `train` function in `caret` to fit the model, which lets me specify it as a glm with binomial family. I then used the `predict` function on the object generated via `train`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most classification models in R produce both a class prediction and the probabilities for each class. For binary data, in almost every case, the class prediction is based on a 50% probability cutoff.

`glm` is the same. With `caret`, using `predict(object, newdata)` gives you the predicted class and `predict(object, new data, type = "prob")` will give you class-specific probabilities (when `object` is generated by `train`).

You can do things differently by [defining your own model](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) and applying whatever cutoff that you want. The `caret` [website](http://topepo.github.io/caret/) also has an [example](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html#Illustration5) that uses resampling to optimize the probability cutoff.

**tl;dr**

`confusionMatrix` uses the predicted classes and thus a 50% probability cutoff

Max

Answer (score 16):

There is a pretty easy way, assuming `tune <- train(...)`:

```
probsTest <- predict(tune, test, type = "prob")
threshold <- 0.5
pred      <- factor( ifelse(probsTest[, "yes"] > threshold, "yes", "no") )
pred      <- relevel(pred, "yes")   # you may or may not need this; I did
confusionMatrix(pred, test$response)
```

Obviously, you can set threshold to whatever you want to try or pick the "best" one, where best means highest combined specificity and sensitivity:

```
library(pROC)
probsTrain <- predict(tune, train, type = "prob")
rocCurve   <- roc(response = train$response,
                      predictor = probsTrain[, "yes"],
                      levels = rev(levels(train$response)))
plot(rocCurve, print.thres = "best")
```

After looking at the example Max posted, I'm not sure if there are some statistical nuances making my approach less desired.

Comment: In the outputted rocCurve plot, what do the three values mean? e.g. on my data it says 0.289 (0.853, 0.831). Does the 0.289 signify the best threshold that one should use in demarcating the binary outcome? i.e. every case with a predicted probability > 0.289 would be coded "1" and every case with a predicted probability < 0.289 would be coded "0", rather than the 0.5 default threshold of the `caret` package?

Comment: yep that's exactly right, and the other 2 values in parentheses are sensitivity and specificity (honestly, though, I forget which is which)

Comment: also, since then I figured out you can extract it from the roc curve using `rocCurve$thresholds[which(rocCurve$sensitivities + rocCurve$specificities == max(rocCurve$sensitivities + rocCurve$specificities))]` which also gives you the flexibility to weight them differently if you want... one last thing to note is that realistically, you probably want to tune the threshold (like you would with any model hyperparameter) as Max describes [here](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2014/2/1/lw6har9oewknvus176q4o41alqw2ow).